# How redirect the url from h:commandLink

Tags: jsf-2

Do I remember right or the parameter immediate set to true should change the url of the browser?
If it is correct, why doesn't this link works properly?

```
    <h:form>
    <h:commandLink immediate="true" action="/url_page.xhtml" value="Label link"/>
    </h:form>
```

After some research I found a question where the author added the string "?faces-redirect=true" to the url... Is it work like I would? Should I set something else?
Thank you for your help.

P.S.: I tried also h:link but, perhaps, it doesn't execute all thing because after that the next page returns a nullpointerException but the url change as I want...

Solution complete: I change the action of my h:commandLink to call a method that returns /url_page?faces-redirect=true because I found that nullpointer exception was into a servlet-filter...
Thank you @BalusC and @Matt !

Comment: `h:link` ought to work. Your NPE is caused by something else and you would have exactly the same problem when using `h:commandLink` with a redirect.

Comment: @BalusC : well, if I use h:commandLink without any parameters it works properly, if I use h:link the page returns a NullPointerException and if I add faces-redirect=true nothing change form the first method...

Comment: To be clear, you implemented it by changing `action="/url_page.xhtml"` to `action="/url_page.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"`?

Comment: @BalusC : I did an errata corrige, the result if I use h:link and h:commandLink + faces-redirect is the same... however I tried also deleting ".xhtml" from the action/outcome parameter and nothing change...

Comment: @BalusC : ok, I resolve the problem using h:commandLink + faces-redirect... for more information I will edit my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *Do I remember right or the parameter immediate set to true should
>   change the url of the browser?*

No this attribute has a different purpose.

You can use `h:link` for navigation. `h:commandLink` needs a bean method as `action` attribute. The outcome of the action method is the navigation target. If the action method returns `null` or is a `void` method, the current page will be reloaded. If it returns a String, JSF will take it and navigate to that outcome.

If you want to perform a redirection from your action method, you can add `?faces-redirect=true` to your outcome, e.g.

```
return "login?faces-redirect=true";
```

Comment: as I wrote into the others comments if I use h:link or h:commandLink + faces-redirect=true the page returns a nullpointerexception... what could these options change into my application?

Comment: ok, I found the problem... I will edit my question for adding more information.